# SImplest way to trigger script from incoming email (and read a piece of data from that email)

Tags: php, email, soap, authsmtp

I'm using authsmtp to send emails. When a subscriber report an email as spam they send me an email with the recipient address. I then copy the address to my interface to add it to the blocked emails list.

What is the simplest way to automate this? I can change my interface but need for example a service that will receive the email, extract the email address from the email body and call my interface as a soap call (with authentication preferably).

Any ideas ?

(the emails are legitimate by the way, its appx one in 10,000)

Comment: Depends on how you receive the emails. If you receive them locally on Unix, `man procmail`. If they are on a POP or IMAP server, poll that periodically. For Windows MTAs, I imagine it's product-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing this I have a crontask that runs a php script to connect to the mail account of the reply address (unsubscribe@domain) and then my php script will fetch and process any new mail.

So you will be able to process each mail and pass to your API via whatever means you want.

For the php - usually connecting via IMAP - don't have my own code handy but this previous post kind of covers what you're looking for. [Processing incoming e-mail with PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971423/processing-incoming-e-mail-with-php-script)

Comment: Thanks Brian

If anyone has a simpler soultion I'll be more than happy to hear

Comment: Brian, the crontask is manually, right? How often do you have it run and how often do you think would be too much/resource intensive?